# What POST method argument type should I declare to receive un-serialized data?

Tags: rest, webapi

The user is sending me some JSON data to my REST API POST method - which could be 1 of 2 types of data.

I would like to receive whatever is sent over the network - may be as un-serialized string and I can determine which type it is by checking certain keyword.
My question is what type should I declare in my post method to receive this JSON data?

[HttpPost]
public void Post(WhatTypeShouldIDeclareHere type){}

Comment: Is this a ASP.NET thing? Some other language?

Comment: Yes, ASP.NET application.